# Is a replication log necessary to achieve linearizability in distributed store

Tags: apache-zookeeper, etcd, paxos, consensus, raft

The Raft algorithm used by etcd and ZAB algorithm by Zookeeper are both using replication log to update a state machine.

I was wondering if it's possible to design a similar system by simply using leader election and versioned values. And why those system decided to use a replication log.

I my example if we have the following setup

- machine A (Leader), contain version 1
- machine B (Follower), contain version 1
- machine C (Follower), contain version 1

And the write would go like this:

1. Machine A receive Write request and store pending write V2
2. Machine A send prepare request to Machine B and Machine C
3. Followers (Machine B and Machine C) send Acknowledge to leader (Machine A)
4. After Leader (machine A) receive Acknowledge from quorum of machine, it know V2 is now commited and send success response to client
5. Leader (machine a) send finalize request to Follower (machine A and Machine B) to inform them that V2 is commited and V1 could be discarded.

For this system to work, On leader change after acquiring leader Lease the leader machine have to get the latest data version by reading from a quorum of node before accepting Request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The raft algorithm in ETCD and ZAB algorithm in Zookeeper are both using replication log to update a state machine. 
>   I was wondering if it's possible to design a similar system by simply using leader election and versioned values.

Yes, it's possible to achieve consensus/linearizability without log replication. Originally the consensus problem was solved in the [Paxos Made Simple](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf) paper by Leslie Lamport (1998). He described two algorithms: Single Decree Paxos to to build a distributed linearizable write-once register and Multi-Paxos to make a distributed state machine on top of append only log (an ordered array of write-once registers).

Append only logs is much more powerful abstraction than write-once registers therefore it isn't surprising that people chose logs over registers. Besides, until [Vertical Paxos](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/vertical-paxos.pdf) (2009) was published, log replication was the only consensus protocol capable of cluster membership change; what is vital for multiple tasks: if you can't replace failed nodes then eventually your cluster becomes unavailable.

Yet [Vertical Paxos](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/vertical-paxos.pdf) is a good paper, it was much easier for me to understand the [Raft's](http://ramcloud.stanford.edu/raft.pdf) idea of cluster membership via the joint consensus, so I wrote [a post](http://rystsov.info/2016/01/05/raft-paxos.html) on how to adapt the Raft's way for Single Decree Paxos.

With time the "write-once" nature of the Single Decree Paxos was also resolved turning write-once registers into distributed linearizable variables, a quite powerful abstraction suitable for the many use cases. In the wild I saw that approach in the [Treode database](http://treode.github.io/). If you got interested I blogged about this improved SDP in the [How Paxos Works](http://rystsov.info/2015/09/16/how-paxos-works.html) post.

So now when we have an alternative to logs it makes sense to consider it because log based replication is complex and has intrinsic limitations:

- with logs you need to care about log compaction and garbage collection
- size of the log is limited by the size of one node
- protocols for splitting a log and migration to a new cluster are not well-known

> And why those system decided to use a replication log.

The log-based approach is older that the alternative, so it has more time to gain popularity.

**About your example**

It's hard to evaluate it, because you didn't describe how the leader election happens and the conflicts between leaders are resolved, what is the strategy to handle failures and how to change membership of the cluster.

I believe if you describe them carefully you'll get [a variant of Paxos](http://paxos.systems/variants.html).

Comment: I was actually assuming leader election would itself use paxos. 
And was curious to know if the write itself also needed to use paxos or simple quorum is enough assuming the written value contain the leader epoch and value version number.

Answer (score 3):

Your example makes sense. However, have you considered every possible failure scenario? In step 2, Machine B could receive the message minutes before or after Machine C (or vice versa) due to network partitions or faulty routers. In step 3, the acknowledgements could be lost, delayed, or re-transmitted numerous times. The leader could also fail and come back up once, twice, or potentially several times all within the same consensus round. And in step 5, the messages could be lost, duplicated, or Machine A & C could receive the notification while B misses it....

Conceptual simplicity, also known as "reducing the potential points of failure", is key to distributed systems. Anything can happen, and *will* happen in realistic environments. Primitives, such as replicated logs based on consensus protocols proven to be correct in any environment, are a solid foundation upon which to build higher levels of abstraction. It's certainly true that better performance or latency or your "metric of interest" can be achieved by a custom-built algorithm but ensuring correctness for such an algorithm is a *major* time investment.

Replicated logs are simple, easily understood, predictable, and fall neatly into the domain of established consensus protocols (paxos, paxos-variants, & raft). That's why they're popular. It's not because they're the best for any particular application, rather they're understood and reliable.

For related references, you may be interested in [Understanding Paxos](https://understandingpaxos.wordpress.com/) and [Consensus in the Cloud: Paxos Systems Demystified](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/tech-reports/2016-02.pdf)